# Как атрибут "Бренд" назначить вендором (vendor)?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

При экспорте товаров с wordpress некий плагин считывает данные с поля  vendor и формирует xml фид. Но, у меня бренд загружен как атрибут. Как указать, чтобы он считывал данные именно с атрибута бренд?

К примеру:
`if ( $product->sku ) : $output .= "\t" . '<vendorCode>' . $product->sku . '</vendorCode>' . "\n"; endif;`

Здесь мы указали, чтобы плагин считывал данные с поля sku и обернул это в теги vendorCode, хотя изначально плагин пытается найти артикул в поле vendorCode.

Comment: "Бренд загружен как атрибут" , а "sku выводится вместо vendorCode"...как из этого вышло, что бренд нужно поставить вместо артикула?.. ничего не понимаю...

Comment: Не совсем так, с vendorCode это пример того, что нужно сделать. Изначально плагин ищет артикул в поле vendorCode. А артикул загружен у нас в поле sku. Вот мы плагину и показываем, что ищи артикул в поле sku, вместо vendorCode, но выводи в обертке тегов vendorCode. 

Та же, ситуация и с брендом. Плагин ищет бренд в поле vendor, но бренд у нас загружен как атрибут, то есть в поле vendor его нет. Нужно подменить поле vendor полем с брендом, который находится в атрибуте "бренд" и обернуть это в теги <vendor>

Comment: Лучше все это подробно писать в вопросе. Мне лично понять этот вопрос было крайне сложно. И что Вам мешает, к примеру, сделать: `if ( $product->brand ) : $output .= "\t" . '<vendor>' . $product->brand . '</vendor>' . "\n"; endif;`?

Comment: Пробовал, не работает.

Comment: Всего-то и надо, что правильно загрузить данные. В данном случае не в атрибуты, а.. что там у тебя формирует вендоров.

Comment: Не совсем понял ответ.